# When I create an object in Django admin, `form_valid()` method is not called

Tags: python, django, django-admin

When a new `Listing` is created the `form_valid()` method creates a `Bid` object. However, when I use Django Admin to create  new a `Listing` then, the `Bid` object is not created because `form_valid()` is not called.

```py
    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        self.object = form.save()
        # place a bid in the Bids table with the value starting bid and users id
        bid = round(float(form.cleaned_data['starting_bid']), 2)
        Bid.objects.create(
            bid_value = bid,
            bidder = self.request.user,
            item=self.object
        )
        print('form_valid() called')
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

I am new to Python and Django - perhaps the code for creating a new `Bid` be should be in a method on the `Listing` model?

I have tried using an admin model, but haven't had any success:

admin.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from auctions.models import User, Listing, Watchlist, Bid, Comment


class BidAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change) -> None:
        obj.author = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form)
        bid = round(float(form.cleaned_data['starting_bid']), 2)
        Bid.objects.create(
            bid_value = bid,
            bidder = request.user,
            item=obj
        )

# Register models.
admin.site.register([User, Watchlist, Listing, Comment])
admin.site.register(Bid, BidAdmin)
```

Comment: A `ModelAdmin` does *not* work with `form_valid`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ModelAdmin` has no [**`.form_valid(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.form_valid), this is for class-based views (CBVs) that inherit from a [**`FormMixin`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin). The `ModelAdmin` will call the [**`.save_model(…)`** method <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model), so you should implement the logic in that method:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # …
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.author = request.user
        super().save_model(request, obj, form)
        bid = round(float(form.cleaned_data['starting_bid']), 2)
        Bid.objects.create(
            bid_value = bid,
            bidder = request.user,
            item=obj
        )
```

Comment: Thanks, but this isn't working for me. I've created this model `admin.py` and named it `BidAdmin`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @AmbassadorKosh: but here the model is apparently a `Bid` itself, whereas your `form_valid` code hints that it should be an `Item` (some model referred to as `item` in the `Bid` model).

Comment: Yes! I wasn't registering the models correctly. Changing `admin.site.register(Bid, BidAdmin)` to `admin.site.register(Listing, BidAdmin)`, solved this.